# Ajustar texto en celda con API Datatables

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datatables

Alguien me podría ayudar. Como hacer un salto de linea a una celda cuando el contenido es lago y ajustarse al ancho de la columna. Asi lo tengo actualmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo la columna REMITENTE como hacer para que el contenido de la celda se ajuste en 2 lineas. No se si me dejo entender.
Gracias.

Comment: Por defecto ya lo hace, debe ser algun css adicional

Comment: hola seria ideal ver el codigo fuente para poder ayudarte saludos

Comment: Tienes razon Samir. Habia otro css.

Answer (score 1):

Habia un estilo propio llamado defaul.css. Cambie el atributo a white-space:normal

Asi quedo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias